# How to jump to a line in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm doing a pwd generator in ruby and when I get to a certain point of the code I need to return back if the user says that he want to retry to generate the pwd.

```
print "do you want to retry to generate the password? [y/n]"
    retrypwd = gets.chomp
    if retrypwd == y
    (code to jump to some lines ago)
    elsif retrypwd == n
    print "Ok, It'll be for the next time"
end
```

Comment: Embed the logic in a loop and short-circuit with `next` or escape with `break`.

Comment: the line if have to come back is about an hundred lines back so I can't do this

Comment: The distance doesn't matter.  If the logic has to be repeated, it has to be repeated now matter how convoluted it is.  Conversely, if you're doing a lot of unrelated stuff in between you should rethink your logic.

Comment: ok thanks. I'll do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to use a `loop` and break it or repeat it according to your expectations:

```
def try_again?
  loop do
    print "Would you like to try again? Y/N"
    again = gets.chomp.capitalize

    case (again)
    when 'N'
      return false
    when 'Y'
      return true
    else
      puts "Huh? I don't know what that means."
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can incorporate this into your main program:

```
begin
  try_password
end while try_again?
```

You will keep trying passwords until `try_again?` returns `false`, which happens if you type "N".

Comment: Some Rubiests don't like returning from a loop. To please them you could replace `return false` (`true`) with `break false` (`true`).